# Lookup User Field in Flow is Failing

Tags: workflow, visual-workflow

I am using the standard lookup in Salesforce Visual Flow and when I looking up to the User using the Contact OWnerId field, the flow fails.

Here are the following fields I put in.

Field API Name: OwnerId
Label: AE Owner
Object API Name: Contact

Error:

```
An error occurred on this Lookup component. Contact your Salesforce admin for help.
```

Comment: One thing to check is do you have sufficient access to the field and object. Also recently, a known issue has been reported which is similar to your error. Check [this](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000003gHUQAY&title=flow-lookup-generates-error-when-the-source-object-has-a-record-type). May be the same cause and error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since this  is a standard look up  and standard object contact, its not a FLS issue. looks like issue with salesforce . please raise the case with them

Answer (score 1):

I used a custom lookup field instead (lookup to user) in a flow lookup component to make it work. Original ownerId field never worked so this was the best solution at the time. And when you do create record just populate the OwnerId with chosen value on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

CreatedById also works (and is a standard field)