# Lookup component in flow not working with User Object

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a scenario to use the lookup to User from a Custom object. But I get error "Looks like you don't have access to this field, or the object or field API name is not valid on this Lookup component. Contact your Salesforce admin for help."
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7Tvb.png

Comment: Two things to look at: field level security (does your user have visibility to the field?) and does your user have visibility to the User object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with [Lookup in flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_ref_elements_screencmp_lookup.htm&type=5), make sure to validate these two points:-

1. Field API Name:- The API name of a lookup field on the source object. In the image you have linked to question, it says User, I wonder if you have any field with api name User.
2. Object API Name: The API name of the source object.

For example, if you trying to look account while creating contact, You should use AccountId in Field API Name and Contact in Object API Name.

**consideration:-**

1. The running user of a flow must have the Create permission on the
   source object. For example, to search a contact’s account, the
   running user must have the Create permission on the Contact object.
2. A custom lookup field to a User record isn’t supported

Comment: Thank you so much ! this has clarified my doubts.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using ownerId, you should use CreatedById if you want to look up users

Example for lookup to users related to a case.

[image]

Note: Make sure that the running user has **"Create"** permissions to that object to prevent error message: *“*Record is not createable"**

Answer (score 1):

I used a custom lookup field instead (lookup to user) in a flow lookup component to make it work. Original ownerId field never worked so this was the best solution at the time. And when you do create record just populate the OwnerId with chosen value on the screen.
Another thread - [Lookup User Field in Flow is Failing](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/307115/lookup-user-field-in-flow-is-failing?rq=1)